# Data Rate Limits for each API call for Cool , heat and Auto(Heat/Cool)

Tags: android, nest, nest-api

I am facing issue to change temperature with in minute, if we change temperature  more than two time in minute, then data is not changing in Thermostat and showing Over limit of API calls. But if we change it after every minute it is working fine. is there any limit in current library and sample code provided in nest site? We are struck over here, Please provide details. Please provide us if any new libraries provide for nest.

Thanks in Advance
Teja.

Comment: see https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/data-rate-limits

Comment: Yes Cristian, I checked link, they mention that there is a limit per hour for service calls. But I want to know what is limit for minute? right now according to Demo code provided by nest, there is limit of each API call per minute and we can do 60 API calls  per hour. I want to know is there any library to increase limit?

Answer (score 0):

No libraries will allow you to break the rate limit policy. The rate limits are dynamic and can change depending on your implementation. For example firebase and streaming connections don't need as many GET calls. You shouldn't be changing the set point more than once a minute either way.